# How to populate quantities between 2 transaction dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with dates,  Products, Quantity (Purchase is positive and Sales are negative) and Price, like the following

`Date        Prod_Name   Qty Price
1/3/2017    ProductA    8   150
1/9/2017    ProductB    2   170
1/11/2017   ProductA    -8  160
1/12/2017   ProductB    -2  180`

I would like to have a query that generates the total quantity by product for every business day like the following:

`date        A   B
1/3/2017    8   0
1/4/2017    8   0
1/5/2017    8   0
1/6/2017    8   0
1/9/2017    8   2
1/10/2017   8   2
1/11/2017   8   2
1/12/2017   0   2
1/13/2017   0   0`

Comment: Getting the various products into their own columns like this requires a sql PIVOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require to generate dates and need to do sum over windowing function as below:

```
Declare @startdate date = '2017-01-03'
Declare @enddate date = '2017-01-13'

;with Datescte as (
Select top (datediff(day, @startdate, @enddate) +1) Dt = Dateadd(day, Row_Number() over (order by (Select null))-1, @startdate) 
    from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
    ), cte2 as (
    Select * from 
        ( Select [Date], Prod_name, Qty from #Dates ) a
        pivot (max(Qty) for prod_name in ([ProductA],[ProductB])) p
    )
    Select Dt as [Date], sum(ProductA) over(order by Dt) as [A], Coalesce(sum(ProductB) over(order by dt),0) as [B]
        from Datescte d
        left join cte2 d2
        on d.dt = d2.Date
```

First CTE generates dates between two dates.
Second CTE does pivot for two products and query returns sum based on date column

Comment: That works and your method to fill the dates is simpler than what I had, thank you

Comment: Welcome... Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

WITH C AS
(

SELECT        Date, Prod_Name,qty,price
FROM          YourTable

)
SELECT *
FROM C
  PIVOT(SUM([qty])
    FOR Prod_Name IN ([ProductA],[ProductB])) AS P;

Comment: Please clarify, are you having issues pivoting on products or producing the dates with no corresponding values?

Comment: Pivoting on products

Comment: How are you defining a business day? If there is a possibility of having no sales in a single day, how are you determining a 'non-business' day from a day that just happens to have no sales?

Comment: So my response should produce the desired results. It may need to be tweaked to fit your exact requirements though. If you have many possible products you may want to look into using a dynamic pivot. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17510.t-sql-dynamic-pivot-on-multiple-columns.aspx

Comment: Business days is all days except week end, I want values on holidays
Some days has no transactions and no volume (in that case I'd like to have 0 as value)